# How to call an asynchronous function and get its response inside another function?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have written code to fetch categories out of an API of Chuck Norris.
The problem is whenever I fetch I ask for the data. When I used `console.log(data)` in my fetch function it gave me the data. But when I call the fetch function in other function it doesn't work.

My getCategory() gives *undefined*and my generateRandomQuotes(e) gives

*Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0*

If anyone can help me with my problem I would be grateful.

Sorry about my bad English.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);

function init(){
document.querySelector('#generateQuote').addEventListener("click", generateRandomQuote);
getCategory();
}

function doFetch(url){
    fetch(url, {
        cache: 'no-cache',
        headers: new Headers({
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        })
    }).then(function (response) {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
        }
        else {
            throw new Error('No response');
        }

    }).then(function (data) {
        return data;

    })
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
}

function generateRandomQuote(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let url="https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random";
    let fetchQuote = doFetch(url);
    let quote = JSON.parse(fetchQuote);
    console.log(quote);
}

function getCategory(){
    let url="https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/categories";
    let fetchCategories = doFetch(url);
    console.log(fetchCategories);

}
```

Comment: doFetch is still async, you need to wait for it to load the request before you can parse the result. I would consider rewriting the function to accept a callback and go from there

Comment: Also once you have sorted out your async issue,  if your using `response.json()`  don't then `JSON.parse` or your parsing an object, and will get `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1` instead.. :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this code: -

> This is using `async` / `await`, that's new with modern JS.

```js
    function init(){
          document.
          querySelector('#generateQuote').
          addEventListener("click", generateRandomQuote);
          getCategory();
     }
 

    function doFetch(url){
      return  fetch(url, {
          cache: 'no-cache',
          headers: new Headers({
          'Accept': 'application/json'
      })
      }).then(function (response) {
          if (response.ok) {
              return response.json();
      }
          else {
              throw new Error('No response');
          }

      }).then(function (data) {
          return data;

      })
          .catch(function(error){
              console.log(error);
          });
      }

   async function generateRandomQuote(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      let url="https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random";
      let fetchQuote = await doFetch(url);
      console.log(fetchQuote);
    }

    async function getCategory(){
      let url="https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/categories";
      let fetchCategories = await doFetch(url);
      console.log("inside getCatagoty", fetchCategories);
    }

    init()
```

```html
<input type= "button" value ="demo" 
id = "generateQuote"
></input>
```

Comment: What exactly have you done here to solve the problem?

Comment: @Keith I guess the `await` in the getCategory() function

Comment: @Luca indeed, but he needs to say..  Also this could be made into a working snippet, it still wont' work though, due to `JSON.parse` still been there. :)

Comment: Yep, I see that too

Comment: @Keith `generateRandomQuote` will obviously throw error you have no dom element with id `#generateQuote` and that `id` has nothing to do with fetching data

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the promise:

Change

```
fetch(url, {
```

into

```
return fetch(url, {
```

And to wait for it:

```
doFetch(url).then(function(quote){
    console.log(quote);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a callback parameter to your `doFetch()` function, like so:

```
function doFetch(url, callback){
    fetch(url, {
        cache: 'no-cache',
        headers: new Headers({
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        })
    }).then(function (response) {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
        }
        else {
            throw new Error('No response');
        }

    }).then(function (data) {
        callback(data); // call the passed function with the returned data

    })
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
};
```

After that you can use the function in your code:

```
function generateRandomQuote(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let url="https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random";
    doFetch(url, (data) => {
        let quote = data.value;
        console.log(quote);
    });   
}
```

Comment: If it's already a promise, why not use it as a promise? Adding a callback only makes it heavier to manage.